# How to use transform:rotate in CSS with Cytoscape.js?

Tags: css, cytoscape-web, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

How to use CSS's property for styling  pie chart such as, [1](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/) , [2](http://atomicnoggin.ca/blog/2010/02/20/pure-css3-pie-charts/)

```
.pie {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          -moz-border-radius: 50px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
          -o-border-radius: 50px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          clip: rect(0px, 50px, 100px, 0px);
     }
     .hold {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          -moz-border-radius: 50px;
          -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
          -o-border-radius: 50px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          clip: rect(0px, 100px, 100px, 50px);
     }
     #pieSlice1 .pie {
          background-color: #1b458b;
          -webkit-transform:rotate(50deg);
          -moz-transform:rotate(50deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(50deg);
          transform:rotate(50deg);
     }
```

in CSS3 for style nodes which are build by [Cytoscape.js](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/) ?

I have already tried following code..

```
style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
.selector("node")
.css({
"content": "data(name)", 
"shape": "data(shape)",
"border-width": 1,
"background-color": "data(color)",
"-webkit-transform":"rotate(140deg)",
"-moz-transform":"rotate(140deg)",
"-o-transform":"rotate(140deg)",
"transform":"rotate(140deg)",
"border-color": "#555",
"height": "data(weight)",
"width": "data(weight)"
})
...
```

but It seem not compatible due to the [cytoscpe.js document](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#style)

So I need to somehow create pie chart in each node there are any solution available?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in another question, this is a planned feature:

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/283

Comment: So, today, how to do it ?